# Angular sanitizing unsafe style pipe not working

Tags: angular

I have an array of products:

```
product_type_one = [
{'description': 'Type one sample one', 'type': 'one', 'image': '../assets/1.jpg'},
{'description': 'Type one sample two', 'type': 'one', 'image': '../assets/2.jpg'},
{'description': 'Type one sample three', 'type': 'one', 'image': '../assets/3.jpg'},
]
```

I am iterating over this array to create mdl-cards and I want each product card to have it's own image background.

My template:

```
 <mdl-card *ngFor="let product of selectedProduct" class="demo-card-event" mdl-shadow="2" style="background-image: url({{product.image}})">
  <mdl-card-title mdl-card-expand>
   <h4>
     {{product.description}}
   </h4>
 </mdl-card-title>
</mdl-card>
```

I do not get any errors so far, but a warning saying `WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value background-image: url(../assets/1.jpg)`

I have created a pipe as following:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';


@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

  transform(html) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }

}
```

Where exactly can I insert it into my template so that images are rendered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping  entire **`url`** statement in the **`bypassSecurityTrustStyle`**

```
   <mdl-card *ngFor="let product of selectedProduct" class="demo-card-event" mdl-shadow="2" [style.background-image]="product.image | safeHtml">
      <mdl-card-title mdl-card-expand>
       <h4>
         {{product.description}}
       </h4>
     </mdl-card-title>
    </mdl-card>
```

and then,

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtml {
  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

  transform(html) {
    return this.sanitization.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('url(' + html+ ')');
  }
}
```

Comment: This somehow has no effect, shouldn't there be something like url(...) ? If I write it in this formate without safeHtml tag, it doesn't even give me warning i.e. style.background-image="product.image"

Comment: yeah it should. or try  [style.background-image]="product.image | safeHtml"

Comment: and in your pipe this.sanitization.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('url(' + image + ')');

Comment: Hey this last answer worked! TrustStyle. Thanks a lot :)